# Minimizing sequences and topology (direct method)

Tags: optimization, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

To show the importance of the choice of the topology for the direct method we have been assigned the following exercise which I've not been able to solve due to my lack of understanding on how **strong** and **weak** topologies on Sobolev spaces are defined:

> Consider the Sobolev space $H_0^1[(0,1)]$ and the functional
>   $$F(u):=\int_0^1\left(|u'(t)|^2-1\right)^2+u^2(t)\thinspace dt$$

Show that:

- $F$ is lower semi-continuos wrt the **strong** $H_0^1$ topology
- $F$ is not semi-continuos wrt the **weak** $H_0^1$ topology
- minimizing sequences are precompact wrt the **weak** $H_0^1$ topology
- minimizing sequences are not precompact wrt the **strong** $H_0^1$ topology

As a hint he sketched the following graph which suggests a sequence of functions in $H_0^1$ converging to the zero function (pointwise) but whose derivatives have modulo $1$ $\mathcal{L}^1$-a.e (where they are defined).

### [image]

Intuitively it is clear that this sequence of functions is a minimizing sequence as $u_n\searrow 0$ and $u_n'=1$ (in the above sense) so that the functional converges to $0$, but how to formalize this? In particular what is to be understood under these notions of **strenght** of the topology?

I hope to have been clear enough, many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that functional well defined in $H^1$? I see a term like $|u'|^4$, which will be infinite for a lot of $H^1$ functions.

Comment: That is true, but infinity should not a problem here, as we're looking down (for a minimizer) and not up.

Comment: gg sir boon het.